# Equivalent Characterizations of Rigid Bodies & Angular Velocity Interpretation

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity, constrained-dynamics

In rotational kinematics, there seem to be two common characterizations of a rigid body:

1. A rigid body is any collection of particles with position vectors $\textbf x_1,\textbf x_2,...$ such that the distance $|\textbf x_i-\textbf x_j|$ between any pair of particles $i,j\space $ is conserved, i.e. $\frac{d}{dt}|\textbf x_i-\textbf x_j|=0\iff(\textbf x_i-\textbf x_j)\cdot(\dot{\textbf x}_i-\dot{\textbf x}_j)=0$
2. A rigid body is any collection of particles whose configuration space $\mathcal C$ is isomorphic to $\text{SO}(3)$ (assuming the rigid body's center of mass is fixed in some reference frame).

My questions are:

1. Are these two characterizations truly equivalent to each other? (proof?)
2. In light of the orthogonality relation $(\textbf x_i-\textbf x_j)\cdot(\dot{\textbf x}_i-\dot{\textbf x}_j)=0$ in Characterization #1 above, is it true that the angular velocity vector $\boldsymbol\omega$ of the rigid body obeys the relation $\dot{\textbf x}_i-\dot{\textbf x}_j=\boldsymbol{\omega}\times(\textbf x_i-\textbf x_j)$ for all pairs of particles $i, j$?

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  These are both interesting questions but they should probably be asked separately;  the Q&A format of this forum relies on one well-posed question per post which can be given a "best answer".  I would recommend that you [edit] your post to omit one of these questions, and post that question separately.

Comment: I think the questions are sufficiently related. I almost have an answer ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second question is equivalent to your first. Any rotation in SO(3) will have a dual vector to act in the cross product, and visa versa (the dual vector of a rotation matrix is a well known result). We can thus use your second question as the target of the proof.

The reverse direction is easy. If

$$
\dot{\vec{x}}_{i}-\dot{\vec{x}}_{j}=\vec{\omega}\times\left(\vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_j\right)
$$

Then

$$
\left( \vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_{j}\right)\cdot\left(\dot{\vec{x}_{i}}-\dot{\vec{x}_{j}}\right) = 0
$$

should be obvious (a cross product is perpendicular to each of its operands). Going in the forward direction, we note that for any $\vec{x}_{i}$, $\vec{x}_{j}$, we can always find  $\vec{\omega}_{ij}$ so that

$$
\dot{\vec{x}}_{i}-\dot{\vec{x}}_{j}=\vec{\omega}_{ij}\times\left(\vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_j\right)
$$

by the prior result. This is to say, since the dot product is zero, they are perpendicular and so there must be *some* $\omega_{ij}$ to put into the cross product. We need to show that $\vec{\omega}_{ij} = \vec{\omega}$, the same for all $\vec{x}_{i}$, $\vec{x}_{j}$. Evaluating

$$
\left( \vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_{k}\right)\cdot\left(\dot{\vec{x}_{i}}-\dot{\vec{x}_{k}}\right) = 0
$$

$$
\left( \vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_{j}+\vec{x}_{j}-\vec{x}_{k}\right)\cdot\left(\dot{\vec{x}_{i}}-\dot{\vec{x}_{j}}+\dot{\vec{x}_{j}}-\dot{\vec{x}_{k}}\right) = 0
$$

$$
\left( \vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_{j}\right)\cdot\left(\dot{\vec{x}_{i}}-\dot{\vec{x}_{j}}\right) + \left( \vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_{j}\right)\cdot\left(\dot{\vec{x}_{j}}-\dot{\vec{x}_{k}}\right) + \left( \vec{x}_{j}-\vec{x}_{k}\right)\cdot\left(\dot{\vec{x}_{i}}-\dot{\vec{x}_{j}}\right) + \left( \vec{x}_{j}-\vec{x}_{k}\right)\cdot\left(\dot{\vec{x}_{j}}-\dot{\vec{x}_{k}}\right) = 0
$$

$$
0 + \left( \vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_{j}\right)\cdot\left(\dot{\vec{x}_{j}}-\dot{\vec{x}_{k}}\right) + \left( \vec{x}_{j}-\vec{x}_{k}\right)\cdot\left(\dot{\vec{x}_{i}}-\dot{\vec{x}_{j}}\right) + 0 = 0
$$

$$
\left( \vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_{j}\right)\cdot\vec{\omega}_{jk}\times\left(\vec{x}_{j}-\vec{x}_{k}\right) + \left( \vec{x}_{j}-\vec{x}_{k}\right)\cdot\vec{\omega}_{ij}\times\left(\vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_{j}\right) = 0
$$

$$
\left( \vec{x}_{j}-\vec{x}_{k}\right)\cdot\left(\vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_{j}\right)\times\vec{\omega}_{jk} + \left( \vec{x}_{j}-\vec{x}_{k}\right)\cdot\vec{\omega}_{ij}\times\left(\vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_{j}\right) = 0
$$

$$
-\left( \vec{x}_{j}-\vec{x}_{k}\right)\cdot\vec{\omega}_{jk}\times\left(\vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_{j}\right) + \left( \vec{x}_{j}-\vec{x}_{k}\right)\cdot\vec{\omega}_{ij}\times\left(\vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_{j}\right) = 0
$$

$$
\left( \vec{x}_{j}-\vec{x}_{k}\right)\cdot\vec{\omega}_{ij}\times\left(\vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_{j}\right) = \left( \vec{x}_{j}-\vec{x}_{k}\right)\cdot\vec{\omega}_{jk}\times\left(\vec{x}_{i}-\vec{x}_{j}\right)
$$

I don't know how much rigor you are looking for, but I would say that since $\vec{x}_{i}$, $\vec{x}_{j}$, and $\vec{x}_{k}$ are completely arbitrary, we must have that

$$
\vec{\omega}_{ij} = \vec{\omega}_{jk} = \vec{\omega}
$$

the same for all vectors $\vec{x}$. If the last step is insufficient for you, I can try to show it, but I think that is one of those things that is less illuminating than the space to show it warrants.